# in spite of setting full screen mode, i cannot draw on whole

Tags: android

I've created an app in full screen mode, but the area available for drawing does not fit the whole screen. Basically, it looks like this:

http://wstaw.org/m/2011/08/29/29082011001.jpg

I checked sample apps from sdk, and they seem to have the same problem.

The code is here: https://bitbucket.org/dodek/net.qwpx.snake/src

Any suggestions?

Comment: Put the height/width of the canvas into the log (use Log.i) and compare that to the possible height/width.  You may want to try explicitly setting it, rather than having it in your layout, also.

Comment: What do you mean by "possible height/width"?

Comment: The height and width of the display.

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate `<supports-screens>` element in your manifest, along with an appropriate `<uses-sdk>` element with the `android:minSdkVersion` attribute. Android on your phone thinks that your app was written in 2008 before such screen sizes were supported and is attempting to compensate.